# ¿Cómo crear un buscador de cadenas en un texto?

Tags: java, java-8

Mi objetivo es que me muestre la posición de la palabra que esté buscando en el texto de manera independiente, es decir si introduzco `hijo hi mama papa` y quiera buscar `hi` me de la posición de `hi`, no de la subcadena que forma la palabra `hijo`, esto es lo que he intentado.

Si ven el error o errores corríjanme por favor.

```
static int buscarPalabra(String t, String p) {
    int pos = t.indexOf(p);
    
    boolean found = Arrays.asList(t.split(" ")).contains(p);
    if (found) {
        System.out.println(pos);
    }else {
        System.out.println("-1");
    }
    return pos;
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduce el texto");
    String texto = sc.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Introduce la palabra para buscar en el texto");
    String palabra = sc.nextLine();
    
    buscarPalabra(texto, palabra);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te propongo esta forma (a mi parecer, mas sencilla) para tú método `buscarPalabra`

```
static int buscarPalabra(String t, String p) {
    String palabras[] = t.split(" ");
    int pos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < palabras.length; i++) {
        if (palabras[i].equals(p)) {
            pos = i + 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Posicion de la palabra en el texto: " + pos);
    return pos;
}
```

Guardamos en un array de `String`, el texto introducido separados por espacios en blanco.

Recorremos dicho array y comparamos que las palabras que contenga el array coincidan con la palabra a buscar.

Si corresponde guardamos en una variable la posición de la palabra deseada.

Ejemplo completo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindWord {
    static int buscarPalabra(String t, String p) {
        String palabras[] = t.split(" ");
        int pos = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < palabras.length; i++) {
            if (palabras[i].equals(p)) {
                pos = i + 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Posicion de la palabra en el texto: " + pos);
        return pos;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce el texto");
        String texto = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduce la palabra para buscar en el texto");
        String palabra = sc.nextLine();

        buscarPalabra(texto, palabra);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Introduce el texto
  hijo hi mama papa
Introduce la palabra para buscar en el texto
  hi
Posicion de la palabra en el texto: 2
```

Comment: Me has salvado de verdad muchas gracias de nuevo xd